1988 build asbestos?
Would popcorn ceilings in a house built in 1988 have asbestos in them? Did removal years ago with no idea of the potential hazards. Trying to sleep better at night and worry less. 1988 would be extremely unlikely to have asbestos, right? Not sure if anyone has tested and found asbestos in any popcorn from that time frame.
Thanks.

Asbestos is bad for for people who work with it everyday for years/decades.
Decent common floor vacuuming since should have removed any fibres left.
Did you yourself remove it without a mask?  It is the small tiny fibres loosen by sanding(not chunks) that is the most dangerous without a mask, but usually should be a long term use(not a day or two).
If done yourself without a mask, then your doctor should be aware of it for future testing.
I imagine testing of the material is not possible now, but 88 is maybe 50/50 for asbestos.  It is when asbestos was getting a bad name.

Google says it was banned in 1978. Is there really a 50% chance. That someone would use 10 year old stock? I was hoping it would be like 99% vs 1%. Thanks for the comment

@Joe   The ban was probably not a total/destroy all remaining stocks.  More of not to buy/import any more type.  And it depended if it was a home owner/DIY or commercial user.

The companies that had stocks of asbestos were allowed to sell off the stock over a period of years. I think it was supposed to end in 1986. I heard that asbestos still came down from Canada for a time after that. I believe you are right about the continued exposure. A short term exposure, may not be a concern. I worked with it in the 70s off and on, had my lungs checked 5 years ago, since I was a smoker too, nothing significant. I'm blessed.

The likelihood of old stock being used will depend on the area you live.  In the 80s and 90s  housing construction was booming in Fla. it is very unlikely that stock lasted more than a few months if that long.

united-kingdom
Blue and brown asbestos was banned from importation in 1985.
White asbestos was banned in 1999.
According to a booklet from 1999, various products are unlikely to contain asbestos after:

Insulation board (20-45% asbestos): 1982
Lagging (55-100%): 1986
Spray coating (up to 85%): 1986
Asbestos cement (10-15%, sometimes 40%): still in use as of 1999, soon after banned
Textured coatings (paint, plaster): 1988
Electric storage heaters: 1976
Gas heaters: 1988


To sleep better have a MRI test of your lungs to make sure.
Asbestos will create damage to your lungs if you inhale the dust.

Will a relatively small exposure show up on an MRI?

@keshlam if MRI can not detect it you have nothing to worry about. Sensitivity: MRI scans are highly sensitive for detecting lung nodules that are 4 mm or larger, and have a sensitivity of 98.5% for nodules that are 8–10 mm or larger.  If yours are larger than 10 mm, you should worry

@Traveler Doesn't it take years for the damage to show up?

Everything is always a cost/benefit. But if we start giving MRIs to everyone with a one-time possible exposure to asbestos, we might as well start giving MRIs yearly to pack-a-day smokers.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact what is the cost of a live ?

@Traveler Generally on the order of $10 million or so https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_of_life Seriously. There is a cost/benefit issue here. Average MRI (US, quick Google search) $ 1,325. If everyone who ever had a one-time home-improvement possible asbestos exposure (with no aggravating factors such as lifetime heavy smoker or employment in certain industries) got an MRI, the odds of finding a lurking lung cancer or similar issue would likely be far less than 1 in 10,000 MRIs.
